# Using strtok function leads to clearing token before I can use it

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c

I want to design a GPS car tracker that alarms when the speed reaches a certain value and I want to first test the code with the USB to TTL module which is connected to my stm32, and simulate sim808 answers.

When I send the GPS information only the first time the micro responds correctly and the second time I send the GPS information the micro doesn't respond. When I debugged the code I found out that the second time the strtok function makes token zero before getting tokens and therefore the calculated values are zero.

I used strtok before for getting coordinates from sim808 string without problem I don't know what's wrong here and why it works the first time? Here is the string I want to get tokens from:

```
AT+CGNSINF\r\r\n
+CGNSINF:1,1,20210809114956.000,36.343509,59.590779,1029.500,41.25,284.6,1,,1.0,1.3,0.8,,11,7,,,29,,\r\n
\r\n
OK\r\n
```

here is my main code :

```
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include "usart.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

char S = 0x1A;
#define Enter usart_sendchar('\n');
#define CR usart_sendchar('\r');
#define GIM usart_sendchar('"');
#define SUB usart_sendchar(S);
char get_Enter = 0;
uint8_t ch;
uint8_t ch2;
char str1[400];
char str3[400];
int g = 0;
int i = 0;
char flag = 0;
char str_tmp[20];
char str_tmp2[20];
char *p;
char *j;
int sec = 0;
// cheraghchi street start point
float a = 36.345135;
float b = 59.548276;
// cheraghchi street end point
float c = 36.325215;
float d = 59.628918;
// speed limit of cheraghchi
float w = 40.00;

//calling all the functions

void Send_SMS(char *text);
void Send_KEY(char *text);
void del_All_SMS(void);
void CMGF_1(void);
void CMGF_KEY(void);
void CMGR(void);
void CGNSPWR(void);
void CGNSINF(void);
void CGNSINF_t(void);
void Send_CAUTION(char *text);
void AT(void);
void Delay(uint32_t Time);
void USART1_IRQHandler(void);
void interrupt_activation(void);
void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void);
void EXTI1_IRQHandler(void);
void EXTI2_IRQHandler(void);

void Delay(uint32_t Time)
{
    uint32_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (Time--)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            ;
    }
}

void timer_init(void)
{

    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 3);
    GPIOB->CRL &= ~0xF;
    GPIOB->CRL |= 0x3;         //////// GPIOB.0  output push pull
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 11); /* enable clock for TIM1    */

    TIM1->PSC = (7200 - 1); /* set prescaler   = 10KHz  */
    TIM1->ARR = (5000 - 1); /* set auto-reload = 500 ms */

    TIM1->DIER = (1 << 0); /* Update Interrupt enable  */

    TIM1->CR1 |= (1 << 0); /* 0x0001 timer enable       */

    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_UP_IRQn, 1);
}

void TIM1_UP_IRQHandler(void)
{
    sec++;
    if (TIM1->SR & (1 << 0))
    {

        if (sec == 10)
        {

            str_tmp[0] = '\0';
            strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CGNSINF");
            usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
            Enter
            CR
        }
        else if (sec == 20)
        {

            if (p)
            {

                float e[7];
                float m; //for latitude
                float n; //for longitude
                float z; //for speed

                char str2[80];
                const char s[2] = ",";
                char *token;
                // getting the lattitude and longitude
                token = strtok(p, s);

                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    sprintf(str2, " %s", token);
                    e[i] = atof(str2);
                    token = strtok(NULL, s);
                }

                token = NULL;
                m = e[3]; // latitude
                n = e[4]; // longitude
                z = e[6]; // speed
                if (m < a && m > c && n > b && n < d)
                {

                    if (z > w)
                    {

                        Send_CAUTION("CAUTION ! illegal speed ");
                        sec = 0; // for illegal speed
                        p = NULL;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                        {

                            e[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    sec = 0; // for normal speed
                }
                sec = 0; // for out of range streets
            }
        }
    }
    TIM1->SR &= ~0x1;
}

void CMGF_CAUTION(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CMGF=1");
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}

void Send_CAUTION(char *text)
{
    CMGF_CAUTION();

    str_tmp[0] = '\0';

    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CMGS=");

    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    GIM
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';

    strcpy(str_tmp, "+98905xxx6399");

    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    GIM
    Enter
    CR

    usart_sendstring(text);
    Enter
    CR
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';

    SUB

    del_All_SMS();
}

void Send_SMS(char *text)
{
    CMGF_1();
    Delay(500);
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);

    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CMGS=");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    GIM
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);

    strcpy(str_tmp, "+98905xxx6399");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    GIM
    Enter
    CR

    Delay(500);

    usart_sendstring(text);
    Enter
    CR
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(500);
    SUB

    Delay(100);
    del_All_SMS();
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{

    ch = USART1->DR & 0xFF;
    ch2 = USART1->DR & 0xFF;

    if (str1[346] != NULL)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
        {

            str1[j] = 0;
        }
        i = 0;
    }
    else if (str3[240] != NULL)
        for (int g = 0; g < 400; g++)
        {
            str3[g] = 0;
        }
    else
    {
        str1[i] = ch;
        str3[g] = ch2;
        i++;
        g++;
    }
}

void CGNSINF_t(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CGNSINF");
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}

void CMGF_1(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CMGF=1");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}

void del_All_SMS(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CMGD=1,4");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}

void CMGR(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';

    Delay(100);
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CMGR=1");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}
void CGNSINF(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CGNSINF");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}
void CGNSPWR_1(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT+CGNSPWR=1");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}

void AT(void)
{
    str_tmp[0] = '\0';
    Delay(100);
    strcpy(str_tmp, "AT");
    Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR
}

int main()
{
    SystemInit();
    usart_init();
    timer_init();
    AT();

check:
    AT();

    Delay(2000);

    p = strstr(str1, "OK");
    if (p == NULL)
        goto check;

    CMGF_1();
    Delay(500);

    CGNSPWR_1();

    Delay(500);
    del_All_SMS();

    Delay(500);
    p = NULL;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_UP_IRQn);

    while (1)
    {

        if (flag == 0)
        {

            ////waiting for +CMTI: from sim800

            do
            {

                p = strstr(str3, "+CGNSINF:");

            } while (!(strstr(str1, "+CMTI:")));
            Delay(1000);
            // sending AT+CMGR=1 command

            CMGR();

            Delay(2500);
            flag = 1;

            if (flag == 1)
            {
                p = strstr(str1, "+CMGR");
                j = strstr(str1, "loc");
                if (p && j)
                {
                    CGNSINF();
                    Delay(300);
                }
                else
                {
                    del_All_SMS();
                    flag = 0;
                }
                p = strstr(str1, "+CGNSINF:");
                if (p)
                {

                    float a[5];

                    char str2[80];
                    const char s[2] = ",";
                    char *token;
                    // getting the lattitude and longitude
                    token = strtok(p, s);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        sprintf(str2, " %s\n", token);
                        a[i] = atof(str2);

                        token = strtok(NULL, s);
                    }

                    sprintf(str2, "https://maps.google.com/?q=%.6f,%.6f", a[3], a[4]);
                    Send_SMS(str2);
                    p = NULL;
                    Delay(5000);
                    del_All_SMS();

                    flag = 0;

                    for (int k = 0; k < 80; k++)
                    {
                        str2[k] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The call to strtok(() look fine. So I'm guessing that your input string got butchered. Have you verified that it's correct in all calls to strtok()? By the way "p" is a terrible name for a global variable, since you can't track with "find"

Comment: You really need to use better variable names. It's extremely difficult to follow your code.

Comment: Overall, once you've sorted out the usual re-entrancy bugs that your question is about & got working code, then I strongly recommend to submit it for code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Because there is lots bad practice all over this code.

Answer (score 1):

> the second time the strtok function makes token zero before getting
> tokens 
>   I used strtok before for getting coordinates from sim808
> string without problem I don't know what's wrong here and why it works
> the first time?

**strtok()** is used along with a global variable "**char *p;**", while "**TIM1_UP_IRQHandler()**" and "**main()**" are calling **strtok()**. Meantime, [**strtok()**](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) clobbers the "**p**".

If you don't mind, one more advice, aside the style; try ISR not to do strtok(), printf(), or anything not clear how the the function works internally. *ISR can "queue or flag" data and event, then have main() take care of the process.*